# WSProxy.AuthenticationHeader auth = new WSProxy.AuthenticationHeader();

Tags: api

Please let me know which programming language is the below code:

WSProxy.AuthenticationHeader auth = new WSProxy.AuthenticationHeader();

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it is of ASP.Net's code related to Web Service security. You can find its example [overhere](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/376467-using-principalpermission-webmethods-forms-authentication)